# A problem displaying Google Drive on my site

Tags: css, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I want to view the Doc file in Google Drive on my site i did

```
<iframe id="cv" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWg9CtbsObRpCsGHpBRPGNFrQxfdK1Fl/view?usp=sharing">  </iframe>
```

A problem is that the browser shows me :
We cannot display this content in a frame
Content normally appears in this location. However, the publisher prohibits its display in a frame to help you preserve any information entered on this site.
Try
Open in a new window
Report this issue.
When you press Open in a new window It appears but with a full screen. "Do not respect height and width."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the link normally in my browser. On the upper right corner, I can see three dots. Click it, then click `embed item`. A popup with html code segment will appear like this:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWg9CtbsObRpCsGHpBRPGNFrQxfdK1Fl/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Notice that this link is a little different than the link in your question because this one ends with `preview` but your link ends with `sharing`.
Anyway, try this code segment and change height width. I hope this will work. :)